# How to test MongoDB connection?

Tags: mongodb, scala, scalatest

How do I test a MongoDB connection? Here is my code:

```
class MongoDB(val SERVER:String, val PORT:Int, val DATABASE: String, val     COLLECTION: String){

    def establishConnection(): MongoCollection = {

        val mongoClient = MongoClient(SERVER, PORT)
        println("MongoDB client connection: "+ mongoClient)
        val db_handle = mongoClient(DATABASE)
        println("Connected to DB : "+ DATABASE)
        println("Collections present are :")
        println(db_handle.collectionNames)
        assert (establishConnection.size > 0 )

        db_handle(COLLECTION)
    }

    def insert(collection : MongoCollection, document : MongoDBObject) : Unit =          {
        println(collection.insert(document))
    }

    def find(collection : MongoCollection) = {
        println("In find query() :")
        val cursor = collection.find()
        cursor.toList
    }

    def find(collection : MongoCollection, obj : MongoDBObject)  = {
        println("In find query() with condition:")
        val cursor = collection.find(obj)
        cursor.toList
    }

    def findOne(collection : MongoCollection) ={
        println("In findOne query() :")
        val cursor = collection.findOne()
        cursor.toList
    }

    def findOne(collection: MongoCollection, obj : MongoDBObject) ={
        println("In findOne query() with condition:")
        val cursor = collection.findOne(obj)
        cursor.toList
    }

    def update(collection : MongoCollection, query : MongoDBObject, update :   MongoDBObject) = {
        val result = collection.update(query, update) //update or findAndModify can   be used
        result
    }

    def delete(collection : MongoCollection, query : MongoDBObject) = {
        val result = collection.findAndRemove(query);
        result
    }
}
```

Comment: if soemone could links which has sample examples it would of great help

Comment: With Mongo lib are you using?

Comment: i  m very new to test mongodb ..( cashbah ) could you please help with how to start with testing mongodb . instance ( how to ensure db is connected ) ( query functionalities )

Answer (score 0):

You can use  [embedded mongo](http://github.com/flapdoodle-oss/de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo) it's written in java, it first downloads mongo and stores it in home directory ( it downloads only for very first time) and then runs it, you can choose mongoDB version, here is a sample project how to use it from scala test https://github.com/SimplyScala/scalatest-embedmongo.